# PowerBI Filtering by genre

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[Powerbi dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Qqn.png)
The visuals are based on a SQL Server database with loads of movies, genres, customers and watch history. The image shows a clustered column chart which at this moment displays the watch history of all customers. I am trying to filter the chart by a particular movie genre which you can see in the image is Adventure in this case. However when I tick the box nothing happens. 
The relationships are correct I think yet I can't seem to make it work.
[BI Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCeG7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's up:

I believe that you are running into an issue with 'cross filter direction.'

If you look at your relationships diagram, you will notice little arrows (triangles) on the lines connecting the tables.

In your visuals, filtering on / selecting the elements of a table on the 'big' side of your directional join will cause the same filter or highlight on the elements of the 'small' side -- but not the other way around.

Now look at the Movie table -- both joins are moving 'away' from that table.  So clicking/filtering in Movie_Genre isn't going to affect movies, and so it won't affect Watch History.  That's where your counts are - so they don't get filtered.

### What to do:

To get the behavior your want, double-click the connector between the tables.  Look to the lower right of the dialog and find the 'cross filter direction' dropdown and change it from single to both.  This will make the filters you set on Move_Genre work on your counts in Watchhistory.

### Be aware:

I don't really think that this is an issue for the report you're working with because the key in both relationships with 'Movie' is the same field.  But sometimes when you open up these directional filters on tables that join out using different fields you can run into some unexpected behaviors.  Just something to keep in mind for future.

Hope it helps.